# Getting a string from Parse database to display it in a WebView

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, webview

I have a URL stored in my Parse Dashboard and I'm trying to retrieve it then add it to a webview to display its contents.

It is working perfectly when I add the retrieved URL (as a string) to a toast. But it never works when I add it to the webview. It only shows a blank screen.

I have a class in the dashboard named "FavURL" and the column (Key) in it is (URL).

[image: As shown in this image.]

This is my code:

```
public class View_Fav_PDF extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.view_fav_pdf);

            ParseQuery < ParseObject > query = ParseQuery.getQuery("FavURL");
            query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("URL"));
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback < ParseObject > () {
                @Override
                public void done(List < ParseObject > posts, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        List < String > postTexts = new ArrayList < > ();
                        for (ParseObject post: posts) {
                            postTexts.add(post.getString("URL"));
                        }
                        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

                        webView.loadUrl(
                        postTexts.toString());

                        Toast.makeText(View_Fav_PDF.this, postTexts.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(View_Fav_PDF.this, "query error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I just moved the WebView code inside the for loop and changed the variable for it

```
public class View_Fav_PDF extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_fav_pdf);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("FavURL");
        query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("URL"));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> posts, ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {
                    List<String> postTexts = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(ParseObject post : posts){
                        postTexts.add(post.getString("URL"));

                        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

                        webView.loadUrl(
                                post.getString("URL"));
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(View_Fav_PDF.this, postTexts.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(View_Fav_PDF.this, "query error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }
```